# Automatic mesh interface

Tags: network-interface, init-script

I am creating a mesh interface on my raspberry pi's, using the "standard" set of commands:

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add mesh0 type mp
ifdown wlan0
ifconfig mesh0 192.168.202.103
iw dev mesh0 mesh join mymesh
```

I tried putting all of these commands in a .sh script in the `/etc/init.d/` folder, but it gets me nowhere. Does it have anything to do with the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, which looks like this:

```
auto wlan0
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.100.103
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.100.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.200.103
netmask 255.255.255.0
wireless-mode ad-hoc
wireless-essid pi
```

Is there any other way I can automate this process, so that every time system boots, the mesh0 interface is there, with the IP address, and the mesh network chosen? Alternatively, is there anything I am doing wrong with this setup (I suppose in the `interfaces` file), which is preventing the commands from init.d script to be executed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do this by making a `mesh.sh` script containing:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 5
iw wlan0 interface add mesh0 type mp
sleep 1
ifdown wlan0
sleep 1
ifconfig mesh0
ifconfig mesh0 192.168.202.106
iw mesh0 mesh join meshpi
```

Then creating a file called `meshboot` in `/etc/init.d/` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          meshboot
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
start)
sudo /home/pi/mesh.sh
;;
stop)
;;
esac

exit 0
```

And making it run on boot with `update-rc.d meshboot defaults`.

Comment: to disable it, use `update-rc.d -f meshboot remove`